# merge two dataframes on common cell values of different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col3': [1,5,3]})
```

and would like to left merge `df1` to `df2`. I don't have a fixed merge column in `df1` though. I would like to merge on `col1` if the cell value of `col1` exists in `df2.col3` and on `col2` if the cell value of `col2` exists in `df2.col3`. So in the above example merge on `col1`, `col2` and then `col1`. (This is just an example, I actually have more than only two columns).
I could do this but I'm not sure if it's ok.

```
df1 = df1.assign(merge_col = np.where(df1.col1.isin(df2.col3), df1.col1, df1.col2))
df1.merge(df2, left_on='merge_col', right_on='col3', how='left')
```

Are there any better ways to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Perform the merges in the preferred order, and use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) to combine the merges:

```
(df1.merge(df2, left_on='col1', right_on='col3', how='left')
    .combine_first(df1.merge(df2, left_on='col2', right_on='col3', how='left')
                  )
)
```

For a generic method with many columns:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']

from functools import reduce

out = reduce(
  lambda a,b: a.combine_first(b),
  [df1.merge(df2, left_on=col, right_on='col3', how='left')
   for col in cols]
)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     4   1.0
1     2     5   5.0
2     3     6   3.0
```

Better example:
Adding another column to `df2` to illustrate the merge:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col3': [1,5,3], 'new': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3 new
0     1     4   1.0   A
1     2     5   5.0   B
2     3     6   3.0   C
```

Comment: @jezrael because it's more generic, you can merge with multiple columns as input and multiple side columns in df2. Also if you have a conflict, you can set up a preferred order.

Comment: I see, there is multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is possible modify with get merged `Series` with compare all columns from list and then merge with this `Series`:

Explanation of `s`: Compare all columns by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), create missing values if no match by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and for priority marge back filling missing values with select first column by position:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']

s = df1[cols].where(df1[cols].isin(df2.col3)).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
print (s)
0    1.0
1    5.0
2    3.0
Name: col1, dtype: float64

df = df1.merge(df2, left_on=s, right_on='col3', how='left')
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     4     1
1     2     5     5
2     3     6     3
```

Your solution with helper column:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']

df1 = (df1.assign(merge_col = = df1[cols].where(df1[cols].isin(df2.col3))
                                         .bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]))
df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='merge_col', right_on='col3', how='left')

print (df)
   col1  col2  merge_col  col3
0     1     4        1.0     1
1     2     5        5.0     5
2     3     6        3.0     3
```

Explanation of `s`: Compare all columns by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), create missing values if no match by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and for priority marge back filling missing values with select first column by position:

```
print (df1[cols].isin(df2.col3))
    col1   col2
0   True  False
1  False   True
2   True  False

print (df1[cols].where(df1[cols].isin(df2.col3)))
   col1  col2
0   1.0   NaN
1   NaN   5.0
2   3.0   NaN

print (df1[cols].where(df1[cols].isin(df2.col3)).bfill(axis=1))
   col1  col2
0   1.0   NaN
1   5.0   5.0
2   3.0   NaN

print (df1[cols].where(df1[cols].isin(df2.col3)).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0])
0    1.0
1    5.0
2    3.0
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```